# R rolling function error "Error: Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing"

Tags: r

I would like to make rolling mean by time window (e.g., 3 days) rather than
by number of observations (e.g., when these are unequally spaced).

I have a column ("check") with dates in the format "YYYY-mm-dd H:m:s" but unequally spaced.

```
check
2012-01-01 21:05:00
2012-01-01 21:09:00
2012-01-01 22:57:00
2012-01-01 23:21:00
2012-01-02 04:26:00
2012-01-02 04:43:00
2012-01-02 05:06:00
2012-01-02 05:28:00
```

This column has 146,481 rows.
I'm trying to use the following code as suggested in the help section

```
check <- unique(check);
View(check);
z <- zoo(seq_along(check), check);
```

but I get an error message
***"Error: Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing"***

The sequence of the entire code is as follows

```
check <- unique(check);
View(check);
z <- zoo(seq_along(check), check);
g <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "min"))
zm <- merge(z, g)
## - 3-day rolling mean
rollapply(zm, 1440, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)
```

The idea is initially to order the records and to classify them by minutes by replacing by "NA" the non-informed intervals and finally to allow a mean calculation of the by days or more.

If someone could help me with some suggestions.

The result of `dput(check)` is:

> dput(check);

```
structure(list(event_time = structure(c(1325451900, 1325452140, 
1325458620, 1325460060, 1325478360, 1325479380, 1325480760, 1325482080, 
1325482920, 1325483580), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = "event_time", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is after reducing the data to 10 rows.

Comment: Here is the last lines from the output of `dput(check)`. `1241842560, 1241848500, 1241848860, 1242023400, 1242024300, 1257757200, 1257757680, 1260526320, 1260526560, 1291736040, 1291737360, 1453979640, 
1468846800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = "event_time", row.names = c(NA, 
-146481L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`.

Comment: Sorry. I just added the result of the command `dput(check)` in the question (above).

Comment: `check` is n x 1 so `seq_along(check)` is the scalar 1 which is not what you want.  Whatever source you were using undoubtedly was using a vector time series, not an n x 1 series.  Also note that what you are doing will create a row for every minute within the range so it could get very large and that may or may not be ok.

Comment: Yes you are right.
Creating the data by minutes will generate a very large amount of lines, I wanted to first see where it could lead me.

At the beginning I have a time series with a column that records the time of occurrence for each event, it is the column that I have isolated and called "_check_".

I tried first to compute, for each line (ie at each event), the mean of the values of the other columns such as the voltage for 10 days in the past.

I had error messages and it was by trying to fix them that I was driven to this example of "_rollapply_"

Comment: Other problems are that there is nothing to take the mean of (check has a time index but no data values) and the code is trying to take the rolling mean over 1440 points but check;s length is 10.